# CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS giving PhoneNumber?

Tags: java, android, email

Just wondering why I get phone numbers instead of emails when I execute this code? Is there a way around this?

```
Cursor infoEmail = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (infoEmail.moveToNext()) {
            String email = infoEmail.getString(infoEmail.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
            contacts.AddEmail(email);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you inserted phone numbers in the eMail fields? Check your Contacts!